# Как изменить цвет строки Treeview при выделении?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, style, treeview

Установил `ttkthemes` для использования одной темы. К сожалению в ней не реализовано изменение цвета строки при клике на неё. Как можно вручную это настроить?

То есть в самой теме не настроен фокус при нажатии на строку Treeview, из-за этого возникает ряд проблем. Надо как-то включить этот фокус, но я никак не могу понять что и где надо изменить. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Еще раз рекомендую: переходите на PyQt5, в нем гораздо удобнее реализовывать такого рода функции, tkinter для этого мало приспособлен.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, возможно и удобнее, но я хочу полностью освоить библиотеку `Tkinter`, а потом уже перейду на `PyQt5` или `Kivy`

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл только один способ - лезть в tcl файлы темы и вручную менять.

Код(можно найти в файле `ваша_тема.tcl`, если нет, то надо вставить):

```
ttk::style map Treeview \
-background [list disabled $colors(-selectbg)\
        {!disabled !selected} $colors(-window) \
        selected $colors(-selectbg)] \
-foreground [list disabled $colors(-disabledfg) \
        {!disabled !selected} black \
        selected $colors(-selectfg)]
```

Код в первых `[]` реализует цвет заднего фона строки в Treeview. Вторые  `[]` реализуют установку цвета для текста в строках.

`$colors(-...)` - выбор цвета из списка, который присутствует в самом начале кода каждой темы, вместо этого можно вставить самому любой цвет в формате `"#номер"`.

Comment: Ну как, получилось?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, да, всё работает.

Comment: Тогда в ответ стоило бы добавить код.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, когда буду у ПК, тогда добавлю. С телефона это невозможно сделать

Comment: @Sevastopol', это уже ответ. Чуть позже дополню его